# Auto Forward Users Telegram Bot

Tags: telegram-bot

Is there a way that when a user starts talking to a certain number, this user automatically gets forwarded to another number?

We have a business where users come to 1 admin number everytime from like 5 different sites. We want to track where our users come from so we want to set up 5 different phone numbers and forward every user to 1 phone number to see where the user originally came from?

Any suggestions?

I've looked all over the interwebs but I only find stuff related to Messages, not Users.

Kind regards,

Comment: _starts talking to a certain number_ - what number?

Comment: Just a regular mobile phone number? Or telegram username?

Comment: Why not just use forwardMessage method?

Comment: maybe this application helps you - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blank_paper.app.t_forwarder